# Failed to connect to http://localhost:8086, Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running

Tags: connection, localhost, production-environment, influxdb

Searched online but I don't see the solution. I have influx installed: InfluxDB shell version: v1.6.2. But it throws me this error:

Failed to connect to http://localhost:8086: Get http://localhost:8086/ping: dial tcp [::1]:8086: connect: connection refused
Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running.

Answer (score 4):

Just a couple things to check: make sure the the service is running (use the service manager on your OS or the influxd command to check). Another test you can do is to use the actual machine IP address http://:8086 instead of localhost. It could be access is restricted (iptables).

If none of that works, I would check out the discussion on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8912).

Comment: Execute `influxd run` to run the daemon, if you come across permission denied error, use `sudo influxd run` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on a Mac, I had to run `influxd -config /usr/local/etc/influxdb.conf` first before running `influx`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same challenge when I upgraded influxdb to 1.8.9, so I had to downgrade back to 1.8.5.

https://vibhubithar.medium.com/workaround-latest-version-of-influxdb-not-starting-on-raspberry-pi-buster-a8b5afa84fce

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade -y  
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb_1.8.5_armhf.deb
sudo systemctl unmask influxdb.service 
sudo systemctl start influxdb
sudo systemctl enable influxdb.service
```

Answer (score 0):

First check and see if the  influxdb instance is running or not. If it is already running you might need to kill the process by issuing command,

```
ps -ef |grep influxdb

influxdb  5781     1 99 18:15 pts/0    00:00:22 /usr/bin/influxd -pidfile /var/run/influxdb/influxd.pid -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

pkill -f influxdb
```

Once the process is killed, there are chances that port is still in used, which can be verified by issuing command shown below.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN |grep influx

root@db1:/usr/bin# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN |grep influx
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8088          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28558/influxd   
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN      28558/influxd   
root@db1:/usr/bin#
```

In the above example, kill the `process 28558` by issuing command `pkill -9 28558`

Once the port is released,  cd to `/etc/init.d` directory and run the below mention service.

```
root@jvision-db1:/etc/init.d# influx
```

DB instance should come back and can be verified by the `ps -ef |grep influxdb` command.

Also, cd to `/usr/bin` directory and issue below mention command to verify InfluxDB is also available.

```
root@db1:~# cd /usr/bin
root@db1:/usr/bin# ./influx
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.7.9
InfluxDB shell version: 1.7.9
>
```

Answer (score 0):

if :
bind-address = "10.0.0.32:8086"

use
$> influx -host 10.0.0.32
Connected to http://10.2.3.102:8086 version 1.8.10
InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.10

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).